# Deal with defaults categories for all users but with the possibility of editing/deleting them

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to set up a category system on my application.

I would like to offer my users a list of default categories.

Each user should be able to add their own categories or modify existing categories (update or delete) without affecting the categories of other users.

I have a solution but it does not seem ideal to me.

When the user is created, I create entries in the `categories` database for each default category. That means if I have 50 default categories, I have to create 50 entries.

```
public function register() {
  // ...
  Categorie::create(['user_id' => $team->id, 'name' => $name, 'type', $type]);
  Categorie::create(['user_id' => $team->id, 'name' => $name, 'type', $type]);
  Categorie::create(['user_id' => $team->id, 'name' => $name, 'type', $type]);
  Categorie::create(['user_id' => $team->id, 'name' => $name, 'type', $type]);
  Categorie::create(['user_id' => $team->id, 'name' => $name, 'type', $type]);
  Categorie::create(['user_id' => $team->id, 'name' => $name, 'type', $type]);
  Categorie::create(['user_id' => $team->id, 'name' => $name, 'type', $type]);
  /..
}
```

How would you do it?

Comment: let me clear. you have some default categories and users can add category too. a user can edit/delete categories created by him but not the default categories and categories created by others. right??

Comment: For me is good solution. You need categories records for each client. It's like a client creates their own categories and can modify them whenever wants without risk of messing with other clients categories.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon You're right, except that, users can also edit default categories (but not other users' default categories)

Comment: @Daniel I'm afraid that by doing this, it will create performance problems in the database

Comment: every user has default categories?? you are assigning the default categories into every user separately??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Yes, I have to assign each user default categories. For example: each user has in his categories "Red, Blue, Green, Purple". But not all users will want "Red", they can delete it. And create a new one. But it only affects him.